# apparmor doesn't react on my profiling

Tags: apparmor, debian-buster

After instaling debian buster apparmor made my life harder. But I want to familiar with it, so i try to tune profiles (i'm very debianish, so I hope that it is temporary, next upgrade should fix most problems I suppose).

One of message looks for me very easy:

```
Jul 25 13:01:03 zenon kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1564052463.462:1334): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/postdrop" name="/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf.d/" pid=25297 comm="postdrop" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

I thought that I should add `/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf.d r,` to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.postdrop`

and reload profile ...
But still denied. So i thought maybe I should also add 
`/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf.d/* r,` to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.postdrop`
and reload profile...

But still denied...

Maybe I add it to wrong place???

whole file:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#    Copyright (C) 2002-2005 Novell/SUSE
#
#    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#    modify it under the terms of version 2 of the GNU General Public
#    License published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# vim:syntax=apparmor

#include <tunables/global>

/usr/sbin/postdrop {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/kerberosclient>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>
  #include <abstractions/postfix-common>

  # This is needed at least for permissions=paranoid
  capability dac_override,
  capability dac_read_search,

  /etc/postfix r,
  /etc/postfix/main.cf r,
  /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf.d r,
  /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf.d/* r,
  /etc/postfix/postfix-script mixr,
  @{PROC}/net/if_inet6 r,
  /usr/sbin/postdrop rmix,
  /var/spool/postfix r,
  /var/spool/postfix/maildrop r,
  /var/spool/postfix/maildrop/* rwl,
  /var/spool/postfix/pid r,
  /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup w,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Existing entries in the profile file

```
/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf.d r,
/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf.d/* r,
```

don't match the `/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf.d/` directory. Only rules that match a trailing slash will match directories. Any of the following should work:

```
/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf.d/ r
/etc/postfix/** r
```

See [apparmor.d - syntax of security profiles for AppArmor](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apparmor/apparmor.d.5.en.html#Globbing) for more details.

You can run AppArmor or a separate profile in **complain mode** to [debug](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse#Debug).